# What's the meaning of this marking on this old transformer?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I'm studying this old power supply, and it has an odd marking on it (probably not, but it is for me).
I'm guessing it is: output in the range [-17v, 17v]
with the possility of having different input voltages, am I right?
What does the S mean ?
[image]

Comment: "S" probably means secondary.  It looks like only 3 connections available on the secondary, so 9 you will NOT be able to parallel the two half secondaries.

Comment: S is for the shield layer in "higher end" transformers. Or actually not the lower end shit. It's a non-looped layer of copper you connect to earth.

Comment: S is for shield. See the green-yellow wire going to that terminal? Green-yellow is reserved for protective earth. (Though it's the "wrong" green-yellow cable here, with bar stripes instead of straight ones.)

Comment: @Asmyldof what's the purpose of the shield, I've found that it is used to get rid of the primary noise, but I'm not sure of the working of it.Can you explain how does it work,(with a diagram if possible, or a link) ?

Comment: This might help explain how a transformer shield connection is used: http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/purpose-of-shielded-isolation-transformer

Comment: One way it works is if the primary insulation breaks down, it connects to Screen, which is connected to safety ground, to blow a fuse, instead of connecting the live mains to the secondary.

Comment: Another question came to my mind: why have selection between close voltages (240v,220v and 110v ...) isn't the standard 220v or 110v which aren't stable anyway, or it wasn't the case back then (60s maybe)?

Comment: It wasn't. Equipment from that date commonly has 100,110,120,210,220,230,240, and 250V voltage selection. Today's '220V' in the UK, Australia, NZ, etc. is still really 240V as it is within the specified tolerance. They changed the *nominal* voltage for international 'harmonization', but not every power turbine in the country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S is for shield. This is a single turn of conductor placed between the primary and secondary designed to be connected to ground. The transformer has a significant stray capacitance between windings. Without the shield, any noise on the primary would be coupled to the secondary. With the shield, the noise goes to ground through the shield connection. The shield is a single turn of foil, insulated so that it does not form a shorted turn.

17-0-17 means a single 34v winding, tapped in the middle. This configuration is often used for symmetrical DC outputs, with the '0' connection going to output common.

Answer (score -3):

It's a multi tap transformer with several selections/taps on the primary to fit the voltage in your region. Very common. S is for secondary. 17 0 17 as in two separate 17 V windings joined at a common point (0 V) which turns out as -17 0 17 if refered to your mid point. Please note that if you stick a multimeter on each output in turn, there is no -17 Vac, just 17 Vac twice but one has oposite polarity of the other winding.

Comment: No, the "17 - 0 - 17' generally denotes a center-tapped winding, not two separate windings. It would be 34V end-to-end.

Comment: And S is not for secondary

Comment: It's hard to be sure with a hand-written label, but @Asmyldof is hinting that the "S" might denote a shield between primary and secondary.

Comment: Then I'll hint it's secondary, sheild or not. Unless you find the person who hand wrote the sticker, we will never know.

Comment: No, it is shield. Incredibly common practice on non-crappy transformers.

Comment: The shield is usually implemented as a piece of copper foil wound on top of the first winding (probably primary in this case) before the secondary is wound. The foil is insulated so that although it wraps completely round the primary it does not create a shorted turn.  Its purpose is to minimize noise on the AC supply coupling into the secondary and the circuits it feeds. The shield has a connection so it can be grounded.