# marking on old transformer?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I've found this marking on an old transformer [image]

This transformer has input voltage selection for the primary and 34v centre tapped secondary, it is used for an old power supply.

My question is: what further information are given by this marking ? (links to the general rules are welcome as well)

Comment: About the only thing that is obvious is that it was probably manufactured in September 1974.  There is no standardization on markings on transformers.  You need to find the manufacturer.

Comment: It's unlikely that no other information is given. There doesn't appear to be anything generic about the part number.

Comment: Could be: produced under 510th version of the production-specs, on assembly-line D, by worker 32, inspected by #431. Having worked on assembly/test lines, that sort of info goes on the stickers.

Comment: 9/74 could be week 9 in 1974.

Comment: @Andyaka it is the same as this one here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303822/whats-the-meaning-of-this-marking-on-this-old-transformer

Comment: Irrelevant to my way of thinking.

Comment: SBA could mean that the manufacturer was Sola Basic, but hard telling how the "A" fits into that unless it has a common meaning in a language other than English. The lack of a metal rating plate could mean it was manufactured only for the manufacturer of a product in which it was a component. It is unlikely that any useful information can be gained from it. I worked for a company that bought transformers with our part number and the initials of the manufactured marked on them.